# Powershell - sending an outlook message with attachement via powershell (January 23, 2022)

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, office365

I tried to send an email with attachement to outlook (365) via powershell, like posted in this scriptlet:

```
$SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SmtpPort = 587
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer,$SmtpPort)
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$attfile = "C:\temp\test.txt"
$attatchment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($attfile)
$smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com" #DNS oder IP
$MailMessage.From = "test***@outlook.de"
$MailMessage.To.Add("test***@outlook.de")
$MailMessage.Subject = "PowerShell Email with attatchemnt"
$MailMessage.Body ="This is a email from powershell with attatchments"
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $false
$MailMessage.Attachments.Add($attatchment)

#mit Authentifizierung beim Mail Server (ohne einfach weglassen)
$SmtpUser = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential
$SmtpUser.UserName = "test***"
$SmtpUser.Password = "*****"
$smtp.Credentials = $SmtpUser
$smtp.Send($MailMessage)
```

Completed with the according real credentials,
I got the followin error message:

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Send" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Fehler beim Senden von Mail."
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1

- $smtp.Send($MailMessage)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
  ```

Any Hints, how I can get it run and send mails with attachement via a powershell script?

Kind regards,

Oliver

Comment: does it work without the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# Get the credential
$credential = Get-Credential
## Define the Send-MailMessage parameters
$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer                 = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port                       = '587' 
    UseSSL                     = $true
    Credential                 = $credential
    From                       = 'sender@yourdomain.com'
    To                         = 'recipient@yourdomain.com', 'recipient@NotYourDomain.com'
    Subject                    = "SMTP Client Submission - $(Get-Date -Format g)"
    Body                       = 'This is a test email using SMTP Client Submission'
    Attachment                 = 'C:\Test.txt' # Here you can change your attachment
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure', 'OnSuccess'
}

## Send the message
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Comment: Hello all,
Thank you very much, it works

Comment: For test***@outlook.de

with this SMTPS-Server: smtp-mail.outlook.com
it was working fine.

Thanx,

Comment: all working? @OliverEtzel

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me, **except** that I had to enable ssl.

Maybe add $smtp.EnableSsl = $true

Comment: Hello emo,
yes, this was working with $SmtpServer = "smtp-mail.outlook.com".   


Thanx